# Testimonial autoslider not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement the `Quovolver` http://sandbox.sebnitu.com/jquery/quovolver/ auto slider for the testimonial.

I have included the file 'jquery.quovolver.js' in a folder `js` and called inside the HTML page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.quovolver.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
        $('blockquote').quovolver();
    });
</script>
```

and the HTML was like

```
<blockquote>
    <p>Donec rutrum convallis viverra. Suspendisse vehicula, risus sit amet luctus pharetra, quam ante condimentum metus, porttitor vulputate magna felis quis dui.</p>
    <cite>&ndash; Quote Author (Quote #3)</cite>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
    <p>Suspendisse ipsum urna, pellentesque eget sagittis eget, porta eget ligula. Mauris id posuere nisl. Aliquam sit amet urna lorem. Donec et odio et velit ornare dapibus a sit amet odio. Praesent ornare cursus ante quis fringilla. Vivamus id egestas sapien. Nullam mollis elit eros, ac euismod neque. Nam placerat dictum congue.</p>
    <cite>&ndash; Quote Author (Quote #4)</cite>
</blockquote>
```

and some CSS styles for the `blockquote` and `p`

But seems it doesn't work at my side. Can anybody help me? It just shows the whole blockquotes without the rolling effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's because you link to jQuery after the Quovolver script, which depends on it. Try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.quovolver.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
        $('blockquote').quovolver();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try opening up the developer console in your browser and seeing if there are any errors showing. That might help figure out what the problem is